# The many...the more

Tags: grammaticality, conditional-constructions

I'd like to know if a sentence like the following is grammatically correct and, if not, how it can be written.

> The many friends you have, the more important you are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This idiomatic construction compares two values, of which one increases or decreases proportionately with increases or decreases in the other. It therefore requires two  **comparative** expressions:

> The **more** beer you drink, the drunk**er** you get.
>   The **more** friends you have, the **more** important you are.

A **positive** expression such as *many* cannot be employed in this construction. Perhaps you mean what can be expressed in a conditional construction:

> If you drink **much** beer you will get drunker [*implied: than if you drink only a little*].
>   If you have **many** friends you will be more important [*implied: than if you have only a few*].

Comment: [The Smoker You Drink, the Player You Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smoker_You_Drink,_the_Player_You_Get) was an excellent Joe Walsh album (I still love *Rocky Mountain Way*), but I've never been able to parse the title.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way should be:

> The more friends you have, the more important you are.

The formula is:

> The + comparative + Subject + Verb, the + comparative + Subject + Verb